# How to use onchange in ruby form?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build an interactive search page that update the search result if any change is made to the search form without refreshing the page. I was able to make show the result without refreshing but I still need to click on the search button after I change anything.

My view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">

    <%= form_for(:search, url: search_path, remote: true) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :course_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :course_name, class: 'form-control bottom_margin', onchange: f.submit %>

      <%= f.label "Subject" %>
      <%= collection_select(:search, :subject_id, Subject.all.order(:name), :subject_id, :name, :prompt => true, onchange: f.submit)  %>

      <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-primary top_margin" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

My controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
  def create
    @course = search_params[:course_name]
    @subject = search_params[:subject_id]
    if @subject == ""
      @searchResults = Course.all
    else
      @searchResults = Subject.find_by(subject_id: @subject).courses
    end

    @searchResults = @searchResults.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{@course}%")
    respond_to do |search|
      search.js {render layout: false}
    end
  end
  private
    def search_params
      params.require(:search).permit(:course_name, :subject_id)
    end
end
```

My JavaScript:

```
$("#result").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'search/create', locals: { searchResult: @searchResult } ) %>");
```

Why is on change not working?

Comment: you have `@searchResults` but in view, it's `@searchResult`, typo?also when you said not working, did it give any errors?

Comment: @kasperite Thanks for catching that typo. I do not get any error messages. It's just that the search result do not update until I hit the Search button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I checked the docs: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select and looks like you need to pass `onchange` as part of `html_options` hash ie:

`collection_select(:search, :subject_id, Subject.all.order(:name), :subject_id, :name, :prompt => true, { onchange: "document.getElementById('search-form-id').submit();" })`

The `onchange` event is client side so you can't write `onchange: f.submit`

Wanna see if it works?

Comment: What should be in the 'search-form-id' ?

Comment: that's the id of your search form. It's probably `search`, you can check that in dom inspector

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing what processes on the server side, and the javascript code which runs in the browser on the client.

First, under the `onchange` in your HTML, `f.submit` will evaluate to a submit button, not the javascript code which belongs in the `onchange` attribute.

If you do a View Page Source from your browser, you will see this for your `onchange` attribute:

```
<input class="form-control bottom_margin" onchange="<input type=&quot;submit&quot; name=&quot;commit&quot; value=&quot;Save Search&quot; data-disable-with=&quot;Save Search&quot; />" type="text" name="search[course_name]" id="search_course_name" />
```

What this needs to be is javascript code to do what you want to happen when the `onchange` event occurs.

Further, you are putting the following string in the `<div id="result">` tag:

```
<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'search/create', locals: { searchResult: @searchResult } ) %>
```

This will only put that string in the `div` tag.  It will not evaluate the `render partial`.  All you will have is the unevaluated text in the `div` tag.

This is because `render` has to evaluate on the server before the page is rendered.  The javascript runs later, so it cannot evaluate the string you gave it.

Comment: What you said is true, but how should I fix my code to make it work? I am very new to this kind of three different languages nested together.